# When does God respond?

Tags: vishnu, shiva

To attain god people do a lot of meditation, some worship god by doing rituals with discipline, some do vedic sacrifices.

Consider the case of seeing him (not a material desire). Some people have to do a lot of meditation, but for some people he responds without doing much meditation. **Does it depend on karma of when he has to respond?**

Even the rakshasas do meditate to see Lord Siva, they will be with strict discipline in doing their meditation. But how will Lord Siva decide that it is the time to respond. He knows that the desire of Rakshasas will be evil. Why can't he just test more, the patience of them by taking a very long time? So that they get vexed and stop meditating?

Comment: Different people get results differently. God responds to some in one day, to some after ages. This is because of the yearning of the jiva towards the paramatma. When we pray to God in our puja, we (not all of us, but most) are so pre-occupied with things like "I want this today", "this person has to do this for me", "I did this yesterday". In other words, even though physically we perform prayers and puja's we do not really have that genuine love for God. The moment there is genuine love for God, then even a small whisper from us will call the Lord to come forth and grant us Darshan.

Comment: If you are talking specific to getting boons from the Lord, as in the case of the rakshasas, etc. then yes karma does play a role. But getting material desires full-filled is much less and sub-ordinate to getting Moksha or Mukthi (this depends on the above aspect of love for God, rather than just good karma of an individual), which is the ultimate goal of existence according to some.

Comment: I think God will come to us only when we are the recipient of His grace. One can have the purest heart, greatest austerity but it's not of much use without His grace.

Comment: @Sai "The moment there is genuine love for God, then even a small whisper from us will call the Lord to come forth and grant us Darshan" Unfortunately that never happens, God never comes. God only appears before yogis not before normal persons.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Do not give up! God too loves bhakti and will run to appear in front of the One that loves God. God appears before yogis because they have dedicated their life to God and His service. Normal people are preoccupied with the world whereas Yogis are not. That's the purpose of Sadhana to take the mind away from the world and towards God. Good luck!

Comment: @JavaTechnical When the aspirant has his ego flattened, weeps in total unconditional surrender as a Sarangath the testing God also surrenders  before his Bhaktha, while appearing  in some mysterious way.

Answer (score 4):

When Yogi's heart is in Sattva mode and his heart is clean GOD responds. GOD is your lover only. You need to call him with Love.

Who says God doesn't respond? You do not call him like Mirabai, Narasimha Mehta, Radha and Prahlada.

> Achutam Keshavam, Krishna Damodaram, Ram Narayanam, Janaki Vallabham
>   Kaun kehte he bhagawan aate nahi, tum Mira ke jaise bulate nahi..

Even Rakshasa also become very innocent when they sit in meditation. This is power of God's name only. You must have love when you call anybody. For GOD every body is equal. Even Rakshasa or devata are equal.

Just check yourself. If someone calls you with pure love, can you stop yourself from going to him? Love is GOD. Love calls GOD. Sattva calls Love.

Comment: But still, Lord knows that the Rakshasa will be having an evil desire which he will ask? This will be not good for the universe. Why doesn't the God increase his patience test for Rakshasa?

Comment: God never let change the fate of universe. Look "Uni" means one and "verse" means maintained by. Universe is maintained by GOD himself. Everything that is fate is actually "will" of GOD. We all are just "Neemitta" everything is God's will. Nobody is Rakshasa who meditates for long years They are God's children. But when they misuse and their misfortune leads them towards havoc, they become Rakshasa. God gives choice for one's rise for soul.

Comment: The person who did Tapasya is illegible for boon after exam. And one has full freedom to use granted boon. But boons can not make soul rise. The person who once has changed is tamas nature to sattva, must understand that boon is not neemitta for his soul's fall, boon is to encourage his tapasya. He should choose sattva again. God give them chance and give boon to encourage them. not to lead them towards havoc. They choose their soul's fall by their own Karma. But God encourages good work.

Comment: That means they should not think about that boon when they are meditating. They should put their entire concentration on the Lord?

Comment: When one keeps meditation, first one must forget body. One must see self as "soul", by doing so one have "vairagya" by following the path of "bhakti" by continuously chanting God's name. By doing so one becomes unconsciously closer to GOD. No one can skip Lord mahavishnu's "Maya", only way is chanting GOD's name can make one pass the exam of GOD. 1. Full faith and 2. firm decision of leading self towards GOD, can lead one to "Vairagya". God gives boon after checking exam. Exam is to check one's capacity. After end of meditation, after being conscious and coming back to body , one ask for boon.

Answer (score 1):

Why some people get success in meditation early than others ? 
Here is my view.

> It definitely depends upon karmic laws.
>   Vivekanandaji had said that if you see people getting success in something without much effort then it is certain that they had taken tremendous effort for it in their past lives.
>
> **The great devotee Dhruva**  tried for lord Vishnu's darshana and grace for 1000 consicutive lives. Thus God appeared before him after only six months meditation.
>
> **Mahakavi Kalidasa** had sacrified his head for nine consecutive lives at the feet of maa Kali and she appeared before him without much efforts in his life as Kalidasa.
>
> Why go so far in history... Baba Muktananda(died in 1982) had once told that one of his devotee was Sanyasin for her past 13 consecutive lives and thus within 13 days she acheived a great progress in meditation.
>
> **About Rakshasas**: 
>   The Rakshasas used to do Sakam Sadhna.
>   They used to meditate with some wish.
>   Lord Shiva always knew that the Rakshasas who meditate on him are finally going to acheive Mukti by getting killed by Lord Vishnu;  so he used to appear with almost no time. Lolz!

**Be it lord Shiva or Vishnu, all Gods are mad at their sincere n real devotees so they never discriminate between them like they are Rakshasas n they are bad n bla...bla...**